# Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net, database-connection, connection-string

I'm working with entityframework core,after adding migration and sett connection string during update-database there is a problem issue of initial catalog comes.

[image]

Comment: Don't post code in images

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SQL Server connection string with SQLite. That won't work.